# Prism + Unity regions not loading properly

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm writing application based on WPF and Prism library. I have started with Mef DI support writed some code, which was working.

Then I decided to switch to Unity library.

And here's my problem: Prism does not handling regions properly. RegionManager contains only last created region.

Here's my code:

I have changed Bootstrapper to Unity:

```
public class OrtManBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<Shell>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)this.Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        Container.RegisterTypes(
              AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(),
              WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface,
              WithName.Default,
              WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
        base.ConfigureContainer();
    }


    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        List<Type> types = new List<Type>
        {
            typeof (SearchModule), 
            typeof (ServicesModule),
        };

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo(type.Name, type.AssemblyQualifiedName));
        }
    }
}
```

Shell:

```
<Window x:Class="OrtMan.App.Shell"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:regions="http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF"
        Title="Shell" Height="700" Width="1000">
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Height="75" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0 0 0 5" >
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal"  >
                <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="SearchService" Width="Auto" MinWidth="100" Margin="0 0 10 0"></ContentControl>        
                <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="Ribbon"></ContentControl>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="75" >
            <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="StatusBar"></ContentControl>
        </Border>
        <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0 0 0 5">
            <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainPage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></ContentControl>
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And my simple Module:

```
public class SearchModule : IModule
{
    public SearchModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        RegionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public IRegionManager RegionManager { get; set; }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        //todo: register View
        var searchService = RegionNames.SearchService;
        RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(searchService, typeof (SearchComponent));
    }
}
```

To be sure, I double-checked region names etc.

The problem is that RegionManager seems to register only last region. If i change `var searchService = RegionNames.SearchService;` to `var searchService = RegionNames.MainPage;` component is being registered to MainPage region.

I have no idea what's wrong. I'm pretty sure it has been working under Mef container, and I haven't changed anything that might broke this.

**---EDIT---**

I have double-ckecked: When I create simple application with Unity support, it loads only last region. When I have changed Unity to Mef in this application, it started working correctly.

**--EDIT 2--**

Seems like my types registration in contaier (by convention) broke something. When I changed that to manual registration it seems that everything is working.

But I still have a question about this: Why I cannot use Registration by convention? Or how should I use it to register for example all classes which implements `IService` interface.

Comment: So, if you added this  var foo = regionManager.Regions.ToList(); inside of the constractor, you only get one region? if you set a breakpoint and check.

Comment: Only 1 region is there

Comment: I have double-ckecked: When I create simple application with Unity support, it loads only last region. When I have changed Unity to Mef in this application, it started working correctly.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I have similar project and it works. By comparing your code to mine, I also have this inside of configure container method Container.RegisterType<IShellViewModel, ShellViewModel>(); maybe this helps. You dont have to add that interface if you dont have one btw :)

Comment: I do not have ShellViewModel class/interface. It must be somethig in your implementation.

Comment: Seems like my types registration in contaier (by convention) broke something. When I changed that to manual registration it seems that everything is working.